# I need to assign a random but unique ID to each row of mysql table.The ID should be same if the row contains same values

Tags: java, mysql

I need to assign a random but unique ID to each row in Mysql table.The ID should be same if the row contains same values.

ie., If the 1st row contains [hi,hello,bye] 2nd row contains[gg,hello,bye] and 3rd row contains[hi,hello,bye] then 1st and 3rd row should generate same ID and 2nd row should genetare different ID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the table's primary key?

Comment: hashcode is not working here as it is generating same value for differenrt rows

Comment: On the contrary, a hashcode is exactly what you need. You should look to improve your hashcode implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CRC32(CONCAT(column1, column2, column3)) FROM MyTable.
```

Technically CRC32 is not *random* (but what is?) -- and it has a small chance of generating collisions (different values mapping to the same integer).  But it's a start.

Comment: Its generating same Id for all the rows

Answer (score 3):

MD5 Hash could work. Below is chopped up and quick/dirty code that would need updated, but proves the concept.

```
System.out.println("row1=" + test1 + ":" + tst1.getHash(test1));
System.out.println("row2=" + test2 + ":" + tst1.getHash(test2));
System.out.println("row3=" + test3 + ":" + tst1.getHash(test3));

private String getHash(String inputStr){
    try{
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(inputStr.getBytes());
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
         sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

row1=hi,hello,bye:cfe40e96aa052a484208c2aefb6f39bb
row2=gg,hello,bye:f652785f0e214507e6aea44ecd3ffb7a
row3=hi,hello,bye:cfe40e96aa052a484208c2aefb6f39bb
```

Comment: the below is the code generated for 9 rows.all the 9 rows are different but generating same code for some rows.   code:945beae964b8e547525a9147815307e0
code:2a9bb4f7a223a6b7a161cbdca4621525
code:2a9bb4f7a223a6b7a161cbdca4621525
code:2a9bb4f7a223a6b7a161cbdca4621525
code:39cd3557e954a2d80d7b7177df0c79fd
code:ea40a02fef46750d2ee789ffc7816085
code:ea40a02fef46750d2ee789ffc7816085
code:ea40a02fef46750d2ee789ffc7816085
code:ea40a02fef46750d2ee789ffc7816085

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using and the data for these 9 rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want proof that you don't get collisions everything boils down to concatanating all fields, with a seperator not contained in the fields. Of course this normally will be really long and cumbersome to work with.

What everybody normally does is: feed that String in a Hash function. While theoretically not unique, given a suitable Hashfunction with a large enough result, in should be able to find one that is unlikely to produce a collision during the livetime of the human race. For example git is using such a hash (sha1) and Linus Torvalds writes about the [chance of a accidental collision](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2006/8/28/211065):

> First off, let me remind people that the inadvertent kind 
>     of collision is really really *really* damn unlikely, so we'll quite 
>     likely never ever see it in the full history of the universe.

A different thing is a not so accidental collision. At the very first you should make sure that the string you start with isn't the same for different columns. This means:

- Make sure all columns are contained
- Make sure columns a separated by something not contained in the columns itself. Use escaping if necessary. For example if you just concatenate two columns the values 'abc' + 'def' will give you the same result as 'a' + 'bcdef'

If you have to worry about targeted attacks, i.e. someone actually trying to create entries with the same hash, your best bet is to use a cryptographic hash, possibly one used for password hashing which are often designed to be slow, in order to prevent brute force attacks. Of course this might collide with the requirement for most applications to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of all the values that you care about in a row. It can't be random because, by definition, it must be deterministic -- given the same values, you always get the same ID. If, by "random" you mean "not sequential" most hash functions should satisfy this need.

Theoretically, you cannot guarantee uniqueness as there is always the probability of collisions. That is, different IDs definitely mean that the row values are different but the converse is not always true. Depending on your needs, you might want to implement explicit matching on actual row values whenever matching IDs are encountered. You might also consider using a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) like MD5 or SHA1 and rely on the probabilities being on your side (in fact, any collision you find using a cryptographic hash function would be a breakthrough of some kind in the field).